# A clickable Map in HTML5/css/JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, image, css, mapping

I'm new to web front end development, I was wandering how would I go about mapping an image so that pressing each part would cause a different function to fire off, note that these will be irregular shapes(map of Europe)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SVG with paths would perhaps be a better choice for irregular shapes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Answer (score 2):

If your really want to do this with HTML, you could use the "map"-Element (`<map>`): 
a little example: http://www.imn.htwk-leipzig.de/~tstoppe/europe.html

But this isn't really clean code, i think it would be easier and better if you use SVG